# Does the Git version that ships with GitHub not have the alias feature?

Tags: git, github, alias

I recently installed the GitHub desktop app for Windows, which has its own Git version (1.9.5.github.0 in my case). I'm trying to add some aliases to it, but it doesn't work. I tried

```
git config alias
```

and

```
git config --global alias
```

to see if the command's available, but the returned message is

> error: key does not contain a section: alias

[image: cmd showing git's alias method not being present]

Is it missing from GitHub's version of Git? Or did I miss something really obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this error?

Nothing to do with GitHub or a particular Git version; quite simply, the syntax you're using is incorrect. Using your command on my Macbook throws the exact same error:

```
$ git config alias
error: key does not contain a section: alias
```

### How to define an alias

The proper syntax for defining an alias called `<alias-name>` and equivalent to `git <replacement-text>` is

```
git config alias.<alias-name> "<replacement-text>"
```

with possibly a `--global` flag for declaring the alias in question at the user level rather than at the repository level:

```
git config --global alias.<alias-name> "<replacement-text>"
```

#### Example

The following command defines (at the user level) an alias called `co` for `commit`,

```
git config --global config.co "commit"
```

which allows you to run `git co` as you would `git commit`.

### How to list available aliases

And if you want to list all the aliases defined on your machine, you can even... define an alias for it,

```
git config alias.alias "config --get-regexp ^alias\."
```

and then simply run

```
git alias
```

### Reference

For more details, see the [relevant section of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

Comment: Yes, this solved it! I think the "alias." part was what kept getting into trouble when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to *list* all defined aliases:

```
git config --get-regexp alias
```

It will interprets the name as a regular expression and writes out the key names (`alias.xxx`, `alias.yyy`, ...)

Comment: `^alias\.` is a bit more robust, because the string "alias" can occur elsewhere in config files, e.g. in "aliasesfile" and "aliasfiletype" (both keys under the "sendemail" section).